# Where to put load and save functions

Tags: model-view-controller, save, load

Where should I implement the save and load functions?

In the model, view or controller?

The load function simply loads some data and build the model after the data loaded.
The save function simply saves the model data into binary format.

Comment: Related (but for iPhone): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433902/mvc-can-model-save-load-its-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: in the model.

Longer answer: in a Service / Business Logic layer.

Even Longer answer: You must read MVC tutorials, books or videos (or all of them). Your issue is very basic for MVC.